# Quark Model Family

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, group-representations, quarks, baryons

I have studied the baryon J=1/2 family.i did the $(Y,I_3) $ diagram and started from the highest weight $(\frac{1} {2} ,\frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}) $ which is the proton and used the operators $I_{+-} \ \ U_{+-} \ \ and \ \ V_{+-} $ What i haven't understood yet is how do we get the quark state content of each of the eight particles on the diagram. Also, why does the proton have that weight value? (I want to understand it through group theory)

Comment: $T_+$ sends a d to a u; $V_+$ sends an s to a u; $U_+$ sends an s to a d.  read the quantum numbers of the proton [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511038/highest-and-lowest-su3-f-states).

Comment: I can understand this. What i can't understand is how we explain with group theory that in the octet the baryon on the diagram have 3 quarks as their content since annihilation and creation operators only make a "x" quark into a "y" quark. Thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: Well, quarks were invented to comprise the octet, decuplet, etc... See the linked question and answer. Your book should be detailing that.

Comment: Could you recommend me a good book on group theory for physicists? I was studying from Georgi's "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" but it is difficult to comprehend on an undergraduate level.

Comment: Terrible choice for what you want... For general group theory, *Classical Groups for Physicists*,  by Brian G. Wybourne. For SU(3) and quarks, "Unitary Symmetry and Elementary Particles",  by D. B. Lichtenberg. The two books in the linked answer are also vastly superior.

Comment: @CosmasZachos thank you very much for your help. I am truly grateful!!!